# kotlin non null property getter throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, string, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Why is the field `null` here, and causing a `NullPointerException`?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null:
method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter $this$isBlank
```

This is my Model class :

```
data class ModelChatEntry(
    val id: String,
    val name: String?
): BaseModel, Parcelable {

    var nameInitials: String? = ""
        get() {
            if (field.isNullOrBlank()) {
                field = name?.let { nameStr->
                    val length = nameStr.length
                    val splits = nameStr.split(" ")
                    when {
                        length > 0 && splits.size > 1 -> "${splits[0].first()} ${splits[1].first()}"
                        length > 0 -> nameStr.first().toString()
                        else -> "-"
                    }
                }?:"-"
            }
            return field
        }
```

The layout file code is like this :

```
  <data>
        <variable
            name="bModel"
            type="com.example.myapp.models.ModelChatEntry" />
    </data>

..........

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="@style/AppTheme.TextLight"
                android:id="@+id/tvCompanyPlaceholder"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:background="@color/quantum_lightgreen"
                app:textAllCaps="true"
                tools:text="NN"
                android:text="@{bModel.nameInitials}"
                />
```

Comment: Maybe the object itself is missing? Are you using an extension method somewhere: `fun Something.doIt() { ....nameInitials.get() ... }` ? I think the `this`-reference could be empty. OR you have somehow set `nameInitials` to `null` afterwards... Is this library code? Maybe a `null` String entered your object from the Java side.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: I am calling this nameInitials variable in dataBinding from the same data class object itself

Comment: please show the code

Comment: Updated the code in question @mightyWOZ

Comment: It's a layout of item in adapter implemented with paging 3